# How can I monitor Apache in real time?

Tags: apache-http-server, monitoring, webserver

How can I monitor Apache and get information about users who are connected to Apache? There's a server in my office. I want to know how many people in the office are connected to the it, using my web application, and what their IPs are.

EDIT:
I need to know this information in real time.

Comment: There are a number of ways of solving this problem, but because HTTP is a stateless protocol its probably not easy.  If you wrote the application, why not simply log the details to an SQL database and query that ?

Answer (score 6):

You can configure the [server-status](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_status.html) module for realtime information

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you need a log analyzer.

The most commonly used one is [Webalizer](http://www.mrunix.net/webalizer/) which examines your web server's log files, collates the data, and gives you a new set of web pages containing pretty graphs and charts of visitors and usage.

Comment: does it monitor realtime?

Comment: It parses the logs when you request it to parse the logs - be that once a day, once an hour, or repeatedly with no delay between passes.  It all depends on how you set it up.

Answer (score 0):

If its a Linux Apache server you can also try [Apachetail](http://www.bitser.org/apachetail.shtml) which runs on a Windows desktop and parses/analyses the logs in real-time.

Answer (score 0):

I would second jamespo's answer. You can configure the server-status module. We have been using the same to monitor Apache web-server in our product [AppPerfect Agentless Monitor](http://www.appperfect.com/support/tutorials/monitoring/web-server-monitoring/web-server-monitoring.php). We are able to monitor the data related to busy/idle workers, request rate, total accesses, traffic and CPU load.

Comment: This really sounds more like a comment, especially as you are saying that you agree with another answer. You do not yet have the necessary reputation to post comments everywhere though. I recommend that you stick around, interact with SU in a positive way for a bit, and you'll quickly work up the necessary reputation to more fully interact with the site.